# React Firebase async return of IDs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I have a  project named booking app for companies and I'm trying to add "services" in firebase.

After adding the services I want to retrieve their ID's and add them to "companies" as an array returned b first function if adding the "services".

```
const addedServicesIDs = await addServices(arrayOfServices);

await addCompany(newCompany, addedServicesIDs);
```

The services are added succesfully but I cannot retreive their ID's which I store in the addServices function and returning them as array.

The console.log is working properly.

```
    async function addServices(props) {
  const arrayOfServices = props;
  const arrayOfServicesID = [];

  arrayOfServices.forEach(async (service, index) => {
    console.log(service);
    await db
      .collection("services")
      .add({
        serviceName: service.serviceDetails.serviceName,
        description: service.serviceDetails.description,
        duration: service.serviceDetails.duration,
        price: service.serviceDetails.price,
        capacity: service.serviceDetails.capacity,
        workingDays: service.serviceDayWorking,
      })
      .then((docRef) => {
        arrayOfServicesID[index] = docRef.id;
        console.log("Written Service with ID of ", docRef.id);
      });
  });
 
  return arrayOfServicesID;
}
```

Maybe I'm not understading that well async functions,
I will be very thankful for your help!

Comment: Try deleting the `async/await` and instead keep the `then()` notation. Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found a solution.

1. I used  `const` instead of `var`  ,that's why my variable was not updating.

```js
var AddedServicesIDs = [];
```

2. I have refactored my code

```js
export async function addServices(props) {
      const doc_ref = await db.collection("services").add({
        serviceName: props.serviceDetails.serviceName,
        description: props.serviceDetails.description,
        duration: props.serviceDetails.duration,
        price: props.serviceDetails.price,
        capacity: props.serviceDetails.capacity,
        workingDays: props.serviceDayWorking,
      });
    
      return doc_ref.id;
    }
```

```
for (const service of arrayOfServices) {
    const extractedID = await addServices(service);
      AddedServicesIDs.push(extractedID);
    }
```